# ping summary not showing up with date in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to write a small script that will track network latency with ping.

I need to write to a file and tag each ping entry with a date and time. I need to see the responses in real time and stop the script if the ping times are too long.

I can get the ping results and summary in a file without the date, code below

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Enter Dealer number: "
read deal
echo "Enter IP address: "
read ip
touch ./${deal}_pingtest.txt
ping $ip > ./${deal}_pingtest.txt &
tail -f ./${deal}_pingtest.txt
```

stdout results

```
Enter Dealer number:
test
Enter IP address:
8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=4.87 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=58 time=5.36 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=58 time=8.30 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=58 time=4.48 ms
^C
```

File results

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=4.87 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=58 time=5.36 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=58 time=8.30 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=58 time=4.48 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 2999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 4.488/5.758/8.309/1.506 ms
```

when I add the date to the script the file results never show the stats
script with timestamp

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Enter Dealer number: "
read deal
echo "Enter IP address: "
read ip
touch ./${deal}_pingtest.txt
ping $ip | while read pong; do echo "$(date +%Y-%m-%d\|%H:%M:%S): $pong"; done > ./${deal}_pingtest.txt &
tail -f ./${deal}_pingtest.txt
```

stdout results

```
Enter Dealer number:
test
Enter IP address:
8.8.8.8
2017-08-04|11:31:29: PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
2017-08-04|11:31:29: 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=4.71 ms
2017-08-04|11:31:30: 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=58 time=4.53 ms
2017-08-04|11:31:31: 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=58 time=4.85 ms
2017-08-04|11:31:32: 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=58 time=5.11 ms
2017-08-04|11:31:33: 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=58 time=4.51 ms
^C
```

file results

```
2017-08-04|11:31:29: PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
2017-08-04|11:31:29: 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=4.71 ms
2017-08-04|11:31:30: 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=58 time=4.53 ms
2017-08-04|11:31:31: 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=58 time=4.85 ms
2017-08-04|11:31:32: 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=58 time=5.11 ms
2017-08-04|11:31:33: 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=58 time=4.51 ms
2017-08-04|11:31:34: 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=6 ttl=58 time=4.89 ms
```

Thank you all for any guidance.

Comment: Stdout and file data is the same and both have dates and times so what's the problem?

Comment: the summary statistics at the end. we use them for the final determination of the assessment.  I need to see packet loss and average times.

Comment: try doing 
`& >> ./${deal}_pingtest.txt` , instead of  `> ./${deal}_pingtest.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're using `ctrl-C` at the keyboard to interrupt this script. You need to code things so that the `ping` command is interrupted and emits its summary info, but the shell capturing the output of `ping` survives to capture that summary and emit it to the output file.

This seems like a job for the `trap` builtin to `bash`.

Adjusting your original script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read -p "Enter Dealer number: " deal
read -p "Enter IP address: " ip

trap INT
ping $ip | while read pong; do echo "$(date +%Y-%m-%d\|%H:%M:%S): $pong"; done > "$deal"_pingtest.txt &
tail -f "$deal"_pingtest.txt
```

From the **SIGNALS** section of the man page for `bash`: *Non-builtin commands run by bash have signal handlers set to the values inherited by the  shell  from its  parent.*

The `trap` command above means that the shell running the while loop will not respond to the keyboard interrupt (signal `INT`), but the non-builtin `ping` command will have its disposition reset to default when `bash` launches it, so **will** be interrupted by the keyboard signal. `ping` then emits its summary and exits, and the shell survives to capture all of that output.

You could also structure things so that you don't rely on a background process / `tail` combination:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read -p 'Enter Dealer number: ' deal
read -p 'Enter IP address: ' ip

trap '' INT

ping "$ip" |
while read pong; do
  echo "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d|%H:%M:%S'): $pong"
done | tee "$deal"_pingtest.txt
```

Note that in both I use the `read` builtin and its **-p** option to prompt for input.

Comment: This answer works best for my individual environment.

Answer (score 2):

`ping` will show the stats only if killed with `SIGINT` or `SIGQUIT` (or if the number of pings defined with `-c count` is reached, but you're not using that). From `man ping`:

> When the specified number of packets have been sent (and received) or if the program is terminated with a SIGINT, a brief summary is displayed. Shorter current statistics can be obtained without termination of process with signal SIGQUIT.

So, if you want statistics printed, be sure to kill `ping` like this:

```
pkill ping -SIGINT
```

Comment: I now understand why this is failing, and I usually have 5 to 10 instances of this running, so this kill method wont work for me.